# How to add target blank attribute to external products of WooCommerce blocks in a post

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to add `Products by Tag` block to a post. Some are external products, so how can I add target blank to the button to open a new window? As default, all extnernal links are redirected. I also want to change its button text. I use the following code snippet but it doesn't work.

```
function wp_target_blank( $link ) {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type( 'external' ) ) {

        $link = sprintf( '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" aria-label="%s" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'wp-block-button__link add_to_cart_button' ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
        );
    }

    return $link;
}
```

Please let me know how to do that. Thanks so much.

Comment: check this https://njengah.com/woocommerce-external-product-links-open-in-a-new-tab/

Comment: Thanks, but that seems it's similar to my code

Comment: Define "doesn't work." . What hooks you are using ?

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about coding, just follow a tutorial post. The above code works for add-to-cart on catalog/shop page. The second code is similar to the post you shared and works for single product pages. I tried the above code, just used add_filter(woocommerce_blocks_product_grid_item_html, ....) but it doesn't works. Should I try the second code as the post your shared?

Comment: I avoid blocks so i am not sure what this hook does. From what i see returns $html, $data, $product but not sure what kind of actual data is that. You have to debug and change it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your hints  That's really useful, and I will try other ways to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

**The Original Woocommerce Source code:**

```
protected function render_product( $product ) {
   $data = (object) array(
      'permalink' => esc_url( $product->get_permalink() ),
      'image'     => $this->get_image_html( $product ),
      'title'     => $this->get_title_html( $product ),
      'rating'    => $this->get_rating_html( $product ),
      'price'     => $this->get_price_html( $product ),
      'badge'     => $this->get_sale_badge_html( $product ),
      'button'    => $this->get_button_html( $product ),
   );
 
   return apply_filters(
      'woocommerce_blocks_product_grid_item_html',
      "<li class=\"wc-block-grid__product\">
         <a href=\"{$data->permalink}\" class=\"wc-block-grid__product-link\">
            {$data->image}
            {$data->title}
         </a>
         {$data->badge}
         {$data->price}
         {$data->rating}
         {$data->button}
      </li>",
      $data,
      $product
   );
}
```

**To add target blank to external products:**

```
/**
 * @snippet       Add target blank to external products
 * @author        Vinay jain
 * @compatible    WooCommerce 5
 */
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_blocks_product_grid_item_html', 'add_target_blank_to_externl_products', 9999, 3 );
 
function add_target_blank_to_externl_products( $html, $data, $product ) {
   $target = '';
   if( $product->is_type( 'external' ) ) {
       $target = 'target="_blank"';
    }

   return "<li class=\"wc-block-grid__product\">
         <a {$target} href=\"{$data->permalink}\" class=\"wc-block-grid__product-link\">
            {$data->image}
            {$data->title} //change button text here
         </a>
         {$data->badge}
         {$data->price}
         {$data->rating}
         {$data->button}
      </li>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. Please take a look at this https://i.imgur.com/n15SyDb.png
The above code works for the number #1 (internal link to another page), but I'd like to add target blank to the number #2 (add to cart button). If possible to custom the button text, that's great. Adding the target blank attribute to the number #2 is what I concern. Thanks so much!

Comment: I've written a code for that. Will try out on my local and put a working code for that here.

Comment: I replaced the ahref in your code with the following one, and I got the error

`<a href="%s" aria-label="Learn more" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="" rel="nofollow" class="wp-block-button__link add_to_cart_button">%s</a>`